# I tried updating django_site row to change the name but I have gotten ERROR: column "alt native" does not exist

Tags: django, postgresql

I tried updating django_site to change the name (and later domain) to something more appropriate so that i could use these strings for email sending operations.

I understand it is based on this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/sites/
but I do not know what they are really talking about.

Any help much appreciated.

What I tried:

```
postgres=# update django_site set django_site.name = "alt native";  
ERROR:  column "alt native" does not exist  
LINE 1: update django_site set django_site.name = "alt native";  
                                                  ^  
postgres=# select * from django_site

 id |   domain    |    name       
----+-------------+-------------  
  1 | example.com | example.com
(1 row)
```

Comment: `update django_site set django_site.name = 'alt native'; `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PostgreSQL *double quotes* (`"`) are used to denoted delimited *identifiers*, not string literals. *Single quotes* (`'`) are used for string literals, so you update with:

```
UPDATE django_site SET name = 'alt native' WHERE id=1;
```

You probably should also add a `WHERE …` clause to prevent updating *all* records.

You should also use `name` as column, not `django_site.name`.

Comment: @Ryan: but you are missing the point, it is `'alt native'` with *single* quotes...